# How to consider "pratt" zero method in Wilcoxon Test of R, which is available in Python Scipy?

Tags: r, python, wilcoxon-signed-rank, scipy

I have a dataset of two columns which represent rank data. These ranks are ranged from 1, 2, and 3. To test the difference in medians between these two columns, I am considering the Wilcoxon rank-sum test with Paired samples. The data can be found as 'DemData.csv' in this [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17mu1iPn0zDyRevd-_Aqc0prvRCPA1iT6), where 'dem1m' and 'dem3m' are the columns to be tested.

First, I considered performing this test in Python using `scipy.stats.wilcoxon()` [(Documentation)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.wilcoxon.html). In this module, there is an argument named as `zero_method= "pratt"`, which includes zero-differences in the ranking process. The default `zero_method` is `wilcox` here, which discards all zero-differences. The code considering these two different parameters are as follow:

```
Python 3.6.4
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
data = pd.read_csv('DemData.csv')
dem1m = data.iloc[:, 1].values # x
dem3m = data.iloc[:, 2].values # y
result_wilcox = stats.wilcoxon(dem1m, dem3m, zero_method='wilcox', correction=False)
result_pratt = stats.wilcoxon(dem1m, dem3m, zero_method='pratt', correction=False)
```

The result looks like this:

```
print(result_wilcox)
WilcoxonResult(statistic=394.0, pvalue=0.44822952395895177)
print(result_pratt)
WilcoxonResult(statistic=8769.0, pvalue=3.0819702413935615e-53)
```

I think the `wilcox.test()` [(Documentation)](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.0/topics/wilcox.test) function in R provide more robust results with different parameters. Here is my code:

```
data <- read.csv("DemData.csv")
result <- wilcox.test(data$dem1m, data$dem3m,
                     alternative = "two.sided",
                     paired = TRUE)
```

Here is the result from this function:

```
> print(result)

Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction

data:  data$dem1m and data$dem3m
V = 509, p-value = 0.4522
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

It seems like the p-value from `R` function and the `"wilcox"` version of `scipy` function is same. So, the `R` function here has considered only the `"wilcox"` as `zero_method`. My question is, **can I consider `"pratt"` in the `R` dunction like in `scipy` function?**

Comment: 1. The Wilcoxon rank sum test is not for paired comparisons; the signed rank test is. 2. The rank sum test is not a comparison of medians (at least not without additional assumptions; in the general case it certainly isn't).

Comment: In R, the wilcoxsign_test function in the coin package has an option for Pratt.  I dont know what method the standard wilcox.test function uses.  Either can be used with paired data (signed rank test).

Comment: Another option in R Wilcoxon Signed-Rank using Pratt is wsrTest in the asht package.